# Popen with conflicting executable/path

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I'd like to call the "convert" utility from ImageMagick from my Python script using Popen, like so:

```
Popen(["convert", input_path, "-flop", output_file_path])
```

(The above example simply reverses the image horizontally)

The problem is that when I run the script in Windows, it mistakenly calls the `convert.exe` utility that ships with Windows to convert FAT partitions to NTFS! (located in \Windows\system32)

Now, if I randomly open a command prompt at any directory other than system32, and type "convert", it correctly runs the ImageMagick executable.  So, this implies that Popen is automatically looking in system32.  How can I make it not look in system32, and run the correct executable?

Comment: Have you tried removing the path to system32 from `sys.path`?

Comment: i) system32 is not in `sys.path` ii) `Popen` does not look in `sys.path`.

Comment: `Popen` starts from the current directory. What is your `PATH`-environment variable?

Comment: @Daniel my PATH contains both system32 and ImageMagick.  However, if I manually enter "convert" in the very same directory from which I launch the script, it launches the correct executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for a program is not trivial. I'd **specify the full path to the convert.exe executable** explicitly instead.

`subprocess` uses [`CreateProcess` on Windows that looks in `system32` directory even before any other directory in `%PATH%`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx):

> ... If the file name does not contain an extension, `.exe` is appended.
>   Therefore, if the file name extension is .com, this parameter must
>   include the .com extension. If the file name ends in a period (.) with
>   no extension, or if the file name contains a path, .exe is not
>   appended. If the file name does not contain a directory path, the
>   system searches for the executable file in the following sequence:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The current directory for the parent process.
3. The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute function.

Therefore `convert` is equivalent to `convert.exe` in this case. It first looks in a directory that contains `sys.executable` e.g., `C:\Python27`. Then in the current directory: where you started the Python script from. Then in `system32` where it finds `convert.exe` (filesystem utility, not imagemagick).

You could try to remove system32 directory from `os.environ['PATH']` it may(?) suppress checking it: `Popen(cmd, env=no_system32_environ)` but it is fragile (worse than the explicit path).

There is a related issue on Python bug tracker: ["Subprocess picks the wrong executable on Windows."](http://bugs.python.org/issue18069)

---

`cmd.exe` (the shell) uses different algorithm. See [How does Windows locate files input in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20075097/4279)

If you set `shell=True` then the search sequence for `convert` program:

1. `convert` is not an internal shell command
2. there is no explicit path, so the search continues
3. search the current directory
4. search each directory specified by the PATH environment variable, in the order listed

`%PATHEXT%` defines which file extensions are checked and in what order e.g., convert.com, convert.exe, convert.bat, convert.cmd if `%PATHEXT%` is `.com;.exe;.bat;.cmd`.

Comment: FYI, in Vista and later both `CreateProcess` and the `SearchForExecutable` function in cmd.exe call [`NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684269). If you set the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` it prevents searching the current directory.

Comment: You could also note that, after finding the file, cmd.exe first tries `CreateProcess` (regardless of file extension) and then tries `ShellExecuteEx`, which allows executing arbitrary filetypes. cmd's `start` command is similar but calls `ShellExecuteEx` even if no file is found, such as for registered `App Paths` commands (e.g. `start /b /w python.exe` should work even if python.exe isn't found, since the installer should have registered a default command for "python.exe").

Answer (score 2):

As a completely different approach, you may want to try out [`PythonMagick`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick), a Python wrapper for ImageMagick. This way you can access `convert`'s functions from within Python, and you won't have to spawn outside processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself.  Running a php script in a shell has access to the shell $PATH, while running within Apache does not (at least not a $PATH with the Cygwin dll/exe).

Secondly, use the native Windows notation C:/dir/subdir/pgm within php when on a windows platform and you will get what you expect.

So multi-platform code needs to switch/case the pathing and then reference the decision.