# Capture output of Popen when shell=True

Tags: python, shell, popen

Command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Documents\libexe\tfc\bin\Debug>asc-dir
asc-dir.: directory not linked to an ASC directory //Expected output
```

Test Script:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('asc-dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
(result, err) = proc.communicate()
```

This prints "`asc-dir.: directory not linked to an ASC directory`" to the console but is not saved to `result` or `err`.

How can I save the output to result / err?

When I try `Popen` with `shell=False`, I get the following error:

```
Error:
    WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: >The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. `dir` or `copy`)

Do you really need that?

Comment: As I said, when shell=False, I get the error at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Jahaja: [`shell=True` and `shell=False` differ in how the executable is found on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279). With `shell=False`, OP might need to provide the extension explicitly e.g., `'asc-dir.cmd'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to `Popen`. Otherwise, the standard error will continue to go to whatever file the subprocess inherits from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `shell=True` unless you actually need it. It sounds like the real problem is that Windows cannot find the `asc-dir` executable. Where is it installed/located? Is that directory in the PATH environment variable? If not, you could either add it, or specify the full path to the executable when you call Popen e.g.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\program files\asc\bin\asc-dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: That gives me the following error `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: Ahh, so asc-dir isnt a compiled executable, it's a script or something? in which case it's probably fine to run it with shell=True, my Windows-fu is weak ;-)

Comment: Yeah it's a batch file, sorry - should have mentioned that in the first place

Comment: @Tomcelic: have you tried to provide a full name (with extension) e.g., `'asc-dir.exe'` if `shell=False`? Note: I don't think, you need to provide the full path if the command with `shell=True` manages to find `asc-dir` program.

Comment: @TomDalton: don't use `subprocess.PIPE` unless you read/write using the corresponding pipes.

Comment: He said he was using communicate(), so the pipes need to be set up to get any data... Ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: @TomDalton Shouldn't `\ ` be `/`? And usually we recommend people use `os.path.join` to build path instead of writing in a string.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005: '\\' is appropriate here, notice `r''`. You shouldn't use `os.path.join()` on a single literal string path.