# Python on Windows calling 'make -j4' via subprocess hangs, -j1 works

Tags: python, windows, build, makefile

While porting a build script to Windows I noticed that I can not call `make` with the parallel build option `-j` from *within* python:

```
subprocess.call("make -j4 -f Makefile.win32 target".split())
```

This is on a Windows 7 (in a VM), with Python 3.4.2 (or 2.7.8), GNU Make 3.81 from MinGW. Make itself calls `cl.exe` to compile about 40 C-files. When killing the offending `make.exe` in the Taskmanager, this is the output:

```
make: *** [target] Error 1
make: INTERNAL: Exiting with 1 jobserver tokens available; should be 4!
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I've had similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687479/paralellizing-svn-up-causing-client-freeze

Comment: "Further testing showed that the shell does not make a difference at all." Okay, then don't talk about all those confusing stuff that seem to imply that shell is the culprit. Get to the core of the question immediately.

Comment: Does it work if you call it from the command line rather than from with Python?

Comment: @TheHerk: running it via a cmd.exe shell works (IIRC)

Comment: On an off-chance: try passing close_fds=True to subprocess.call()