# Bigquery command line tool on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, google-bigquery

This may be simple but for quite some time I am getting this error!

On windows and python 2.7

> import subprocess
>
> p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bq"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

When I run normally from command prompt with bq it runs perfectly. 
I am missing something with subprocess and bq.

Thanks

EDIT:
After trying with several solutions provided below I found that when I use "shell=True" most of the commands work on windows shell!

> e.g:  p = subprocess.Popen('dir', shell=True)

Answer (score 2):

The error messages says, that it cannot find the executable you specified. This is most likely caused by the use of backslashes (`\`). Backslashes escape characters in a Python string. You can either replace `\` with `\\` or with `/`. Furthermore you should add the file extension `.cmd`. Try this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq.cmd"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the full name *including file extensions* e.g.,

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(r"C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bq.exe")
```

Notice: `.exe` at the end.

`r''` -- a raw string literal is used to avoid escaping backslashes in the Windows path.

Note: if `r"C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin` is in `%PATH%` then you could use `p = Popen("bq")`. See [Popen with conflicting executable/path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279)

Note: if the actual `bq` filename ends with `.cmd` [as @Antonio suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494388/4279) then ([as said in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279)) `CreateProcess()` Windows function that is used by `Popen()` won't find it unless you specify the file extension explicitly. If you use the shell (`cmd.exe`); it uses different rules (e.g., enumerates `%PATHEXT%` [as said in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279)) and therefore it might find `bq.cmd` even if you give only `bq` (assuming `.cmd` is in `%PATHEXT%`).

> After trying with several solutions provided below I found that when I use "shell=True" most of the commands work on windows shell!

`dir` is an internal shell command. Unless there is some other `dir` program; it won't work without `shell=True` that starts `cmd.exe` (`%COMSPEC%`) on Windows. The reason some commands work with `shell=True` and appear to fail without it is due to the difference in rules that are used to find the executable compared to `shell=False` case (the default). These rules are enumerated [in the link (follow it and read it, I'll wait.  It is 4th time, the link is mentioned in the answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279).

Answer (score 2):

Use one of these:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(["C:/Program Files/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq.cmd"])
p = Popen([r"C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bq.cmd"])
```

bq executable in Google Cloud SDK for windows is called bq.cmd. When calling it from command line, cmd will look the .cmd extension automatically, while python interpreter does not.

Comment: `Popen()` uses Windows API (`CreateProcess()`) to run the child process. It is `cmd.exe` that has different rules, not Python interpreter.