# How to run `pip` in a virtualenv with subprocess.check_call()?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, virtualenv

I'm trying to launch a command in different Python virtualenvs using `subprocess.check_call()`.

To activate the virtualenv (in a Python 2/3 agnostic manner), I simply append the path to my virtualenv `bin` (or `Scripts` under Windows) to the `PATH` and then call `subprocess.check_call()` with this modified environment. Like so:

```
environment = os.environ.copy()
environment['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join([bin_path, environment['PATH']])

subprocess.check_call("pip install -r dev_requirements.txt", env=environment)
```

However, what I notice is that `pip` installs everything in the system Python site-packages. If I change the `check_call()` for:

```
subprocess.check_call("pip install -r dev_requirements.txt", env=environment, shell=True)
```

Then suddenly `pip` operates in the virtualenv as expected.

What bothers me is that in **both cases** running `where pip` gives me the path to the virtualenv's `pip` first.

What could explain this odd behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH is not the first place where `CreateProcess()` used by `Popen()` on Windows looks for the executable. It may use `pip.exe` from the same directory as the parent `python.exe` process. The shell (`cmd.exe`) uses different rules. See [Popen with conflicting executable/path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279).

To avoid the dependency; use the explicit full path to `pip`. You don't need to change the environment in this case:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

check_call([os.path.join(bin_path, 'pip.exe')] + 
           'install -r dev_requirements.txt'.split())
```

Comment: Well, in my case its the user that specifies the command line to execute (and my `pip` example just happens to be one of the commands that fails without `shell=True`) so it's not my call to prepend the full path to pip. I guess using `shell=True` makes sense given that I'm trying to emulate the behavior a user would get by running the command in the terminal. Thanks for the explanation though, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: instead of using the 'pip.exe' can't os.system('which pip') will be the best?

Comment: @ahujamoh: `which pip` might return a wrong `pip` with the unmodified environment otherwise `call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', ..])` could be used. If you have an explicit path to the virtualenv; there is no reason to use `which` (even ignoring other reasons to avoid `which`).