# Porting 'sh 1.11'-based code to Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, porting, imagemagick-convert

All signs seem to indicate that my script is fully operational within a Linux environment and as far as I can tell, the only thing keeping it from working in Windows is my usage of [**sh**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh), which is pretty straightforward:

```
from sh import convert

convert(inputfile, '-resize', r, '-quality', q, '-strip', outputfile)
```

This translates to a bash line:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 350x350 -quality 80 -strip ./small/export.jpg
```

where the `r` and `q` variables are any given resolution or quality.

---

Running this in Windows of course raises an error because 'sh' is completely non-functional in Windows :( I tried replacing 'sh' with the deprecated [**pbs**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbs), but am not having any luck. This is what I've got so far:

```
import pbs

pbs.convert('-resize', r, '-quality', q, '-strip', inputfile, outputfile)
```

The error being raised is:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pbs.py", line 265, in _create
    if not path: raise CommandNotFound(program)
pbs.CommandNotFound: convert
```

---

**Question:**

> **How do I successfully pass these ImageMagick commands from my script while in a Windows environment?**

Comment: why not use subprocess and popen or call?

Comment: @IronManMark20: I'm trying to make sense of how to use those. subprocess seems like the right direction, but it isn't as noob-friendly as sh was.

Answer (score 9):

Following [Kevin Brotcke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231827/kevin-brotcke)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36004813/110488), this is the hack we went with:

```
try:
    import sh
except ImportError:
    # fallback: emulate the sh API with pbs
    import pbs
    class Sh(object):
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            return pbs.Command(attr)
    sh = Sh()
```

Comment: Thanks! Also adding `if hasattr(self, attr): return getattr(self, attr)`  in `__getattr__` retains access to the Command classes via `sh`

Answer (score 4):

`pbs.CommandNotFound` error message is because pbs does not have a `convert` method. Instead you need to use the `Command` method:

```
import pbs
convert = pbs.Command('convert')
```

Now you can use it similar to `sh`:

```
convert(inputfile, '-resize', r, '-quality', q, '-strip', outputfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sub process is your best bet. While, as you said it isn't the easiest to learn, it is really useful. I would look at [this indepth tutorial](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html). Of course, read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) too.

As to your specific problem, `sh` has been around longer than pbs, so it almost certainly has more functions. Looking through the source (`pbs.py`), I found no function named `convert()`. Also, you changed the arguments you called from `sh` to `pbs` (you didn't put an `inputfile`). Finally, there is no function named `convert()` in `sh.py` from the git repo, so I suspect you are confusing it with convert from something else.

Beyond that, you should be able to use `pbs` and `subprocess` in conjunction.

Comment: I think you missed the point of both `pbs` and `sh`. They support dynamic importing, you can literally do `from sh import asdfasdfgqer` and it will look for a program named `asdfasdfgqer` in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You could [use stdlib's `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), to run the command on Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(r'c:\path\to\ImageMagick\convert.exe image.jpg -resize 350x350 -quality 80 -strip small\export.jpg')
```

It is important to provide the full path with the file extension otherwise a [different `convert` command may be chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279).

`check_call()` raises an exception if `convert` exits with non-zero status. You could use `subprocess.call()` and check the status manually instead.