# How to use python code to choose the latest .txt to run in jupyter notebook (only python code)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For your information, when I execute the code below for first time in my jupyter notebook, it is running with no problem:

```
In  []: run txt2pdf.py Results/*.txt
Out []: Writing 'Results\A_2018_04_27_13_55.txt' with 80 characters per line and 
        60 lines per page...
        PDF document: 1 pages
```

But during second time, I execute the same code (want it to run the latest version of the .txt after generated the latest version of the .txt file), it is not able to run:

```
In [] : run txt2pdf.py Results/*.txt
Out []: usage: txt2pdf.py [-h] [--font FONT] [--font-size FONT_SIZE]
              [--extra-vertical-space EXTRA_VERTICAL_SPACE]
              [--kerning KERNING] [--media MEDIA]
              [--minimum-page-length MINIMUM_PAGE_LENGTH] [--landscape]
              [--margin-left MARGIN_LEFT] [--margin-right MARGIN_RIGHT]
              [--margin-top MARGIN_TOP] [--margin-bottom MARGIN_BOTTOM]
              [--output OUTPUT] [--author AUTHOR] [--title TITLE]
              [--quiet] [--subject SUBJECT] [--keywords KEYWORDS]
              [--break-on-blanks] [--encoding ENCODING] [--page-numbers]
              [--line-numbers]
              filename
txt2pdf.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Results\A_2018_04_27_13_57.txt
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2
```

Any helpful solution will be very much appreciate! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess - posting as an answer because it would not fit the comment system.

The first time you have only one file. The wildcard in the command will be shell-expanded to:

```
./txt2pdf.py Results/first_file.txt
```

The second time you have two files so the command is expanded to:

```
./txt2pdf.py Results/first_file.txt Results/second_file.txt
```

And you get an error because txt2pdf is not expecting several filenames (guessing from the error message, we can't really know which txt2pdf.py you are using).

If you are on a Unix-like OS you can try the sh module instead (untested):

```
import sh
from glob import glob
import os

# commenting line by line
def get_last_txt(path):
    return sorted(                         # sort
        glob(path + '/*.txt'),             # all files in the folder
        key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_mtime  # by modified time
    )[-1]                                  # return the last one
```

Then you can do this several times:

```
sh.python('txt2pdf.py', get_last_txt("Results"))
```

You may have to `!pip install sh` if it is not installed yet.

If you are on Windows, go to the Windows Store and install Ubuntu. The Linux sub system for Windows actually transform a Windows machine into a decent development workstation (personally I don't like Linux desktops and use a Mac or Windows with WSSL).

If you are not willing to install Ubuntu from the Windows Store try to replace the sh module by pbs - the syntax is slight different so you must check the documentation or [use this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618906/porting-sh-1-11-based-code-to-windows/46471030#46471030) replacing `import sh` above by this (you may have to `!pip install pbs` or `conda install pbs` first):

```
try:
    import sh
except ImportError:
    # fallback: emulate the sh API with pbs
    import pbs
    class Sh(object):
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            return pbs.Command(attr)
    sh = Sh()
```

Comment: Yes, installing the sh. Trying it now. 
ImportError: sh 1.12.14 is currently only supported on linux and osx. please install pbs 0.110 (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbs) for windows support.

Comment: On Windows 10 I like to install Ubuntu from the Windows Store. Other than that you can install the pbs module - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618906/porting-sh-1-11-based-code-to-windows

Comment: Thanks for your helping Paublo. But the script not run in terminal. It is need to be run in jupyter notebook cell. so this sh.python('txt2pdf.py', get_last_txt("Results")) will not be able to run in it. 
In order to run this code:
run txt2pdf.py [Results/*.txt] [Need to specify the .txt file]

Comment: Oh, how do you start your Jupyter notebook on Windows? I start mine from the Ubuntu shell - but check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, Paublo, launch it from the Anaconda Navigator. :)

Comment: Fair enough. I hope to be covering all bases with my last update. :-)

Comment: Yes, have check your latest edit, now import it have no problem.
It will be best can turn this get_last_txt("Results") into some .txt maybe?
then will be executed the code well.

Comment: is the `sh.python('txt2pdf.py', get_last_txt("Results"))` working? If not, did you get any error?

Comment: <RunningCommand 'python txt2pdf.py Results\\A_2018_04_27_15_15.txt', pid:9856, special_args:{'fg': False, 'bg': False, 'with': False, 'out': None, 'err': None, 'err_to_out': None, 'in': None, 'env': environ({'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\tyson\\AppData\\Roaming', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'TG2-SHARENB1', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV': 'base', 'CONDA_EXE':

Comment: Thanks Paublo. It is working now with this in the jupyter notebook cell:
sh.python('txt2pdf.py', get_last_txt("Results"))
I can get the final output in the Results folder :)
Thanks Paublo!! :)

Comment: You may get a nicer output using `print(sh.python('txt2pdf.py', get_last_txt("Results")).stdout)` but it is just cosmetic.

Comment: Thanks Paublo for this cosmetic tips, the <RunningCommand> not showing in the cell :)
Thank you very much again :)