# Python subprocess call precompiled java

Tags: java, python, subprocess, call

This works from the windows command line:

```
c:\mallet\bin\mallet run
```

I've tried

```
subprocess.call(['c:\mallet\bin\mallet', 'run'])
```

and get an error

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and I've tried

```
subprocess.call(['c:/mallet/bin/mallet', 'run'])
```

and get the error

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What do I have to pass to subprocess.call()?

For completeness sake the complete command I would like to pass is:

```
bin\mallet run cc.mallet.topics.tui.DMRLoader texts.txt features.txt instance.mallet
```

My vague idea is that this is a precompiled java class that I'm calling somehow, but I don't really understand what I'm doing here.

Here are the two mallet-files in the folder `bin`:

`mallet.bat`

```
@echo off

rem This batch file serves as a wrapper for several
rem  MALLET command line tools.

if not "%MALLET_HOME%" == "" goto gotMalletHome

echo MALLET requires an environment variable MALLET_HOME.
goto :eof

:gotMalletHome

set MALLET_CLASSPATH=%MALLET_HOME%\class;%MALLET_HOME%\lib\mallet-deps.jar
set MALLET_MEMORY=1G
set MALLET_ENCODING=UTF-8

set CMD=%1
shift

set CLASS=
if "%CMD%"=="import-dir" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-file" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-smvlight" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="train-classifier" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="train-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.Vectors2Topics
if "%CMD%"=="infer-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.InferTopics
if "%CMD%"=="estimate-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.EstimateTopics
if "%CMD%"=="hlda" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI
if "%CMD%"=="prune" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="split" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="bulk-load" set CLASS=cc.mallet.util.BulkLoader
if "%CMD%"=="run" set CLASS=%1 & shift

if not "%CLASS%" == "" goto gotClass

echo Mallet 2.0 commands: 
echo   import-dir        load the contents of a directory into mallet instances (one per file)
echo   import-file       load a single file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   import-svmlight   load a single SVMLight format data file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   train-classifier  train a classifier from Mallet data files
echo   train-topics      train a topic model from Mallet data files
echo   infer-topics      use a trained topic model to infer topics for new documents
echo   estimate-topics   estimate the probability of new documents given a trained model
echo   hlda              train a topic model using Hierarchical LDA
echo   prune             remove features based on frequency or information gain
echo   split             divide data into testing, training, and validation portions
echo Include --help with any option for more information


goto :eof

:gotClass

set MALLET_ARGS=

:getArg

if "%1"=="" goto run
set MALLET_ARGS=%MALLET_ARGS% %1
shift
goto getArg

:run

java -Xmx%MALLET_MEMORY% -ea -Dfile.encoding=%MALLET_ENCODING% -classpath %MALLET_CLASSPATH% %CLASS% %MALLET_ARGS%

:eof
```

and `mallet`

```
#!/bin/bash


malletdir=`dirname $0`
malletdir=`dirname $malletdir`

cp=$malletdir/class:$malletdir/lib/mallet-deps.jar:$CLASSPATH
#echo $cp

MEMORY=1g

JAVA_COMMAND="java -Xmx$MEMORY -ea -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -classpath $cp"

CMD=$1
shift

help()
{
cat <<EOF
Mallet 2.0 commands: 

  import-dir         load the contents of a directory into mallet instances (one per file)
  import-file        load a single file into mallet instances (one per line)
  import-svmlight    load SVMLight format data files into Mallet instances
  train-classifier   train a classifier from Mallet data files
  classify-dir       classify data from a single file with a saved classifier
  classify-file      classify the contents of a directory with a saved classifier
  classify-svmlight  classify data from a single file in SVMLight format
  train-topics       train a topic model from Mallet data files
  infer-topics       use a trained topic model to infer topics for new documents
  evaluate-topics    estimate the probability of new documents under a trained model
  hlda               train a topic model using Hierarchical LDA
  prune              remove features based on frequency or information gain
  split              divide data into testing, training, and validation portions

Include --help with any option for more information
EOF
}

CLASS=

case $CMD in
    import-dir) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors;;
    import-file) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors;;
        import-svmlight) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Vectors;;
    train-classifier) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify;;
        classify-dir) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Classify;;
        classify-file) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Classify;;
        classify-svmlight) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Classify;;
    train-topics) CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.Vectors2Topics;;
    infer-topics) CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.InferTopics;;
    evaluate-topics) CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.EvaluateTopics;;
    hlda) CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI;;
    prune) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors;;
    split) CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors;;
    bulk-load) CLASS=cc.mallet.util.BulkLoader;;
    run) CLASS=$1; shift;;
    *) echo "Unrecognized command: $CMD"; help; exit 1;;
esac

$JAVA_COMMAND $CLASS $*
```

Comment: I typed `assoc c:\mallet\bin\mallet` to windows command line and the return was `File association not found for extension c:\mallet\bin\mallet` I tried it also with `/` with same results.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in the answers?

Comment: The problem is that `c:\mallet\bin\mallet` is not exceutable, what exactly is `c:\mallet\bin\mallet`? If it is a java file why not run it with java?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. There are two files in the folder named mallet: mallet.bat (begins `@echo off`) and mallet (begins `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: And this is on windows?

Comment: Have you tried running `subprocess.call(['c:/mallet/bin/mallet.bat', 'run'])` ? Or `subprocess.call(['cmd', 'c:/mallet/bin/mallet.bat', 'run'])` ?

Comment: I had not, but now that I have I can report that they both work as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Artturi I've posted that as an answer, with some explanations (I'm not a regular Windows user -- so I didn't get too much into details, though). Please note in your case, the error message was rather confusing because you had in fact a `mallet` (without extension) file in the same folder. But it was a bash (i.e. Unix shell) executable -- so not understood by "Windows".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a program without extension, the Windows shell will try several standard extensions (`.BAT`, `.EXE`, ...) in order to *guess* the file you are trying to call.

If you want to execute your program without a shell to perform that look-up phase, you need to pass the full name of the batch you are trying to execute -- incl. the `.BAT` extension:

```
subprocess.call(['c:/mallet/bin/mallet.bat', 'run'])
```

Comment: related: [on the difference between `CreateProcess` (default) and `cmd.exe` (`shell=True`) command lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you pass the `shell = True` argument to `subprocess.call()`. However, it poses security issues, so make sure you look at the documentation and understand how it works.

```
subprocess.call(['c:/mallet/bin/mallet', 'run'], shell = True)
```

Also, when using strings to identify paths that contain backslashes, make it a raw string (`r"This is a raw string!"`), so that it doesn't implement anything else (such as newline tokens).

If my above suggestions don't work, there are only two things that I can thing of:

1. The file you are trying to execute may not be an application file (`.exe` file). I don't work with Windows so I'm not sure about this one, but it could likely be a possibility.
2. Something in the file(s) is broken or something like that.

[`subprocess.call()` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

[`subprocess.call()` Security Issues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any idea what kind of security issues using shell=True poses? I think it quite unlikely that mallet would be a security risk. I tried the `r` in front of the string, but got the same `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` error.

Comment: The only security issues that `shell = True` imposes is if commands are based from external input. I'll set a link to the docs. I doubt you'll have to worry about it in this case anyway though ;)

Comment: Your answer works and I'm going to accept it in a day or two, but would just like to hear if anyone has a suggestion how to get the `subprocess.call()` to work without `shell = True`.

Comment: Sure no problem. I should probably point out that you will always need `shell = True`. In other functions, such as `os.system`, it's like processing `subprocess.call` with the `shell = True` argument.

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe the problem is with the backslashes.

From their [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html):

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character.

So you probably should do:

```
subprocess.call(['c:\\mallet\\bin\\mallet', 'run'])
```

Comment: OP notes that they tried forward slashes, which are interpreted the same way as backslashes and don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried and got the `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` error.