# Python will not execute Java program: 'java' is not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to get Python to call a Java program using a command that works when I enter it into the command line.

When I have Python try it with subprocess or os.system, it says:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

From searching, I believe it is because when executing through Python, it will not be able to find java.exe like a normal command would.

Comment: [this answer describes how the search is performed on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279). What happens if you run `subprocess.check_call('java -version')` or `subprocess.check_call('java -version', shell=True)`? What happens if you run `java -version` from the command-line (`cmd.exe`)?

Answer (score 0):

give absolute path of java location 
in my system path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe`

Comment: yes   if that succeed then try to solve with environment variable.

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: first check java command working or not in cmd .  if it is ok then try to execute os.getenv('PATH') in python it must be return java lib path.   if everithing is ok then   it will be complicated problem

Comment: @AndyFeely Just to be sure: You have quoted any backslash in that path, especially a '\b' has to be written as '\\b'‽  And when using a shell (`os.system()` or `subprocess` with `shell=True`) you also have to escape space characters.

Comment: How do you get past the space in the program files?

Comment: I'd skip using an intermediate shell/cmd.exe and use '/' in paths instead of '\'. Then it's: `subprocess.check_call(['C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe', '-version'])`. You may have to change the path to your actual Java installation of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the PATH variable to point to the java location.

import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join([java_env])

java_env will be a string containing the directory to java.

(tested on python 3.7)