# Running a batch file in another directory in python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I want to run `mybat.bat` file located in MyFolder which is different from the current directory. I used the following code:

```
subprocess.Popen(["mybat", MyArg],
                  cwd=MyFolder,
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
"WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
```

I should mention that if I replace `mybat` with another program in the PATH such as `notepad` it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes. I do have mybat.bat file in MyFolder.

Answer (score 2):

The working directory is changed only in the child process i.e., `cwd=MyFolder`  does not make `os.path.join(MyFolder, "mybat.bat")` available. Try:

```
p = Popen([os.path.join(MyFolder, "mybat.bat"), MyArg], cwd=MyFolder)
```

You could [use `%~dp0` inside your bat-file, to get the directory where the bat-file resides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/4279) instead of `cwd=MyFolder` as [@eryksun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358818/running-a-batch-file-in-another-directory-in-python#comment52609529_32359372).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Your solution solved the problem too.

Comment: A properly written batch file shouldn't in general require setting `cwd` to find files relative to itself. It should use `%~dp0` to get the fully-qualified path of the batch file, i.e. the [d]rive and [p]ath of the .bat file (command-line argument 0).

Answer (score 0):

adding shell=True to command solved the problem.

Comment: you could avoid `shell=True` if you provide the explicit `.bat` extension and the complete path to the bat-file if the error persists. See [this answer on the difference between how the search for an executable differs in `shell=False|True` cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279). Look at [Windows questions in the subprocess tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info)