# How do we execute "./<script_name>" from python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am currently writing a python script that will automate make files that are there in various directories under my project. The directory structure is like this :

```
                Repository
                  |
                  |
            _____ |_____
           |            |
         Builds        src
           |            |
         __|__        __|__
   Scripts   xyz     abc   3rdpartytools
    |                          |
    conf                     boost
    |                          |
script1.py                     b2
```

script1.py is my python file and all the make files that I want to execute are present under the 3rdpartytools directory. boost directory is just an example. Now, I want to execute file `b2`. From the shell, ./b2 works.

I tried using subprocess.call from the python file. I tried

`call(["cd"," ../../../src/3rdpartytools/boost;./b2"])` but i get `/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: ../../../src/3rdpartytools/boost/b2: No such file or directory`

The same command when I execute from shell, works fine.

Python 2.7 and CentOS.

Comment: try `call(["../../../src/3rdpartytools/boost/b2"])`

Comment: Tried that out, but I get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I tried `call(["cd","/home/tejas/Repository/src/3rdpartytools/boost;./b2"])` but I still get `/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: /home/tejas/Repository/src/3rdpartytools/boost/;./b2: No such file or directory`....  Works from shell though!

Comment: Use `os.chdir()` to change directories before using `call()`.

Comment: related: [Running a batch file in another directory in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32358818/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `subprocess.call` in multiple ways. `subprocess.call` will not actually call a shell, unless you specifically ask it to. Thus, the symbol `;` has *no special meaning*. Since it is in the same string as the path, you try to `cd` into `../../../src/3rdpartytools/boost;./b"`, *not* doing a cd and then executing the function.

Use [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to go to the appropriate directory, then call `./b2` using `subprocess.call(["./b2"])`.

Comment: @Tejas: if you want to change the working directory only for a single command then  use `call(os.path.join(wdir, 'b2'), cwd=wdir)` (no need to call `os.chdir()`)